# Errors in UILabel

Tags: ios, interface, uilabel

I'm trying to use the FXlabel when following [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/design-build-a-small-business-app-project-setup/) (Adding a gradient label section) tutorial. This is some of the code inside my viewDidLoad method:

```
self.logoLabel = [[FXLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(14, 11, 280, 87)];

[logoLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:45]];

[logoLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[logoLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[logoLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 2)];
[logoLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[logoLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[logoLabel setText:@"Attorney Biz"];

[logoLabel setGradientStartColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:163.0/255 green:203.0/255 blue:222.0/255 alpha:1.0]];
[logoLabel setGradientEndColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Unfortnuately, I get an error `"No visible @interface for 'UILabel' declares the selector 'setGradientStartColor'"` at the second-to-last line and `"No visible @interface for 'UILabel' declares the selector 'setGradientEndColor'"`

Can somebody explain how to remove these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the logoLabel declaration in header file and import "FXLabel.h" in implementation file.

```
@class FXLabel;
@interface SomeClass:SomeParentClass
{
    FXLabel *logoLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) FXLabel *logoLabel;

@end
```

Comment: It was a UILabel in the header file. Duh!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel* logoLabel;
```

to this

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet FXLabel* logoLabel;
```

after you add the FXLabel component. I was scratching my head for a while at the errors.